# Can I dynamically turn off validation in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a search form where I can search on one of two fields. Only one of the two is required. Is there a way to cleanly do this in the MVC provided validation?

Comment: But, is specifically one is always required and the other optional, or is the case where one of the two should be filled, not caring which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is server validation, you could create a Custom Validation Attribute for this:

```
[ConditionalRequired("Field1","Field2")]
public class MyModel()
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a custom validation attribute.. something like the following:

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true )]
public sealed class ConditionalRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "Either '{0}' or '{1}' must be provided.";
    public string FirstProperty { get; private set; }
    public string SecondProperty { get; private set; }

    public ConditionalRequiredAttribute( string first, string second )
        : base( _defaultErrorMessage )
    {
        FirstProperty = first;
        SecondProperty = second;
    }
    public override string FormatErrorMessage( string name )
    {
        return String.Format( CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString,
            FirstProperty, SecondProperty );
    }

    public override bool IsValid( object value )
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( value );
        string originalValue = properties.Find( FirstProperty, true ).GetValue( value ).ToString(); // ToString() MAY through a null reference exception.. i haven't tested it at all
        string confirmValue = properties.Find( SecondProperty, true ).GetValue( value ).ToString( );
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( originalValue ) || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( confirmValue ); // ensure at least one of these values isn't null or isn't whitespace
    }
}
```

Its a little verbose, but it gives you the flexibility to able this attribute directly to your model as opposed to applying it to each individual field